# Edit content of JSON file imported to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js to:

1. Query an external API.
2. Save JSON result to file.
3. Import query result to MongoDB.

Example of code:

```
//Query the API and save file

var file = '../data/employees.json';
tl.employees.all(function(response) {
fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(response, function(key, value) {
    var result = value;
    return result;
}, 3, 'utf8'));

//Inserts API response above to MongoDB

var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
    db.collection('employees').insert(response, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Step 2: Inserted Employees");
        callback();
    });
};
```

This is all working fine, and I'm getting the following JSON saving to file and importing to MongoDB:

```
{
 "data": [
{
 "full name": "Keith Richards",
 "age": 21,
 "userName": "keith1@keith.com",
 "employeeDetails": {
    "id": 102522
}
},
{
"full name": "Jim Morrison",
 "age": 27,
 "userName": "jim@jim.com",
 "employeeDetails": {
    "id": 135522
 }
}
]
}
```

The problem is that this gets imported to MongoDB as 1 object because of the "data" part.

Like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ae5ceac10d7a5005fc8370"),
"data" : [ 
    { // contents as shown in JSON above ..
```

This makes aggregation and matching really hard (or not possible).

Is there a way of stripping out the "data" part and only importing the contents of it, so each 'employee' would become it's own object like this:

```
[
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58ae5ceac10d7a5005fc8370"),
 "full name": "Keith Richards",
 "age": 21,
 "userName": "keith1@keith.com",
 "employeeDetails": {
    "id": 102522
}
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("234332c10d7a5005fc8370"),
"full name": "Jim Morrison",
 "age": 27,
 "userName": "jim@jim.com",
 "employeeDetails": {
    "id": 135522
 }
}
]
```

Comment: Why not inserting `response["data"]` instead of `response` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can parse the Json before sending it to file. After getting the result, use parseJSON(data) to check if it contains "data" field. if yes, get the arrays inside that and store them to file.
Basically, I have explained a bit more to what @Bertrand has said.
Hope this helps.